# set hook with temporary object

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

i expect the hook to be updated(and i want every time to keep only one object i dont want to save previous value)
my hooks:

```
  const [rooms, setrooms] = useState([]);
  const [roomFilter,setRoomFilter]=useState([])
```

function to update roomFilter hook:

```
  const deleteR=(i)=>{
      var temp=rooms.filter((element,index)=>(index==i))
    setRoomFilter([temp[0].Name])
```

somehow it shows nothing in roomFilter hook after update
i have tried also initiakize my hook like this:

```
  const [roomFilter,setRoomFilter]=useState({})
```

i dont understand why

edit
i am using function deleteR like this:

```
<Route exact path="/"component={() => { return <HomeScreen rooms={rooms} filter={deleteR} room={roomFilter} /> }}
```

from HomeScreen component i have two more components :
HomeScreenRooms and Room
function roomFilter is been sent from app to HomeSCreen >to HomeScreenRooms

HomeScreen:

```
<HomeScreenRooms rooms={props.rooms}  filter={props.filter} room={props.roomFilter} />
```

HomeScreenRooms:

```
 {props.rooms.map((element) => {
            return ( <div style={{ width: "100px",height: "100px",position: "relative",
             left: "-150px",top: "-100px",display: "inline" }}>

                <Link to="/room"><button onClick={() => {props.filter(element.index) }}  style={{ width: "116px",height: "116px",backgroundColor: element.color,position: "relative",fontWeight: "bold", color: "white",fontSize: "18px", border: "3px solid rgb(84,84,84)" }}>
                    <p>
                      <span>{element.room} </span>
                    </p>
                    
                    <p>
                      <span
                        style={{ fontWeight: "bold", color: "rgb(84,84,84)" }}>{element.Name}  
                         </span>
                    </p>

                  </button>
                 
                </Link>
```

Comment: how are you using the deleteR function?

Comment: i am sending this function to 2 other components :HomeScreen ,HomeScreenRooms and from HomeScreenRooms i am calling function deleteR i have edited my code also with more details , i know that roomFilter is not updating because i have tried to print it to consolo.log(roomFilter) and it shows an empty array @Gandzal

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
const deleteR = (i) => {
  setRoomFilter((prevState) => {
    var temp = prevState.filter((element, index) => index == i); //consider using a unique id
    return [temp[0].Name];
  });
};
```

note: I would recommend you use some sort of unique identification to remove from a list, and not an index.

Comment: well i can see in app that roomFilter is really updating thats gerat! i wanted too asj though ... when you write return [temp[0].Name] is it whre do i return this temp? to deleteR?
@Gandzal

Comment: is it working as you expected now? the setRoomFilter function returned from useState can also accept a function as a parameter, where the current state is passed in as a parameter. Whatever is returned from this function is what the state will be set to. Particularly useful to solve asynchronous calls and solve stale closures

`setState((state) => newState))`